# Create JSON with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to create a JSON file with jq from the result of the command "lsb_release"

What i have done :

```sh
if [ -x "$(command -v lsb_release)" ]; then
    lsb_release -a  | jq  --raw-input 'split("\t") | { (.[0]) : .[1] }' > ubuntu_release.json
fi
```

the result is

```json
{
  "Distributor ID:": "Ubuntu"
}

{
  "Description:": "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
}

{
  "Release:": "20.04"
}

{
  "Codename:": "focal"
}
```

but i want the result

```json
[
    {
      "Distributor ID:": "Ubuntu"
    },
    {
      "Description:": "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
    },
    {
      "Release:": "20.04"
    },
    {
      "Codename:": "focal"
    }
]
```

can anybody body help me ? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, when we want to create an array from a stream of inputs, we can use `--slurp`/`-s`. But when combined with `--raw-input`/`-R`, this causes the entire input to be provided as a single string (that contains line feeds).

Slurping can also be achieved using `--null-input`/`-n` and `[ inputs | ... ]`. And this works as desired for text files.

```sh
jq -nR '[ inputs | split("\t") | { (.[0]) : .[1] } ]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bJMiO9Bub4) on jqplay

---

That said, I suspect you will find the following output format more useful:

```json
{
  "Distributor ID": "Ubuntu",
  "Description": "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS",
  "Release": "20.04",
  "Codename": "focal"
}
```

This can be achieved by simply adding `| add`.

```sh
jq -nR '[ inputs | split(":\t") | { (.[0]) : .[1] } ] | add'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/b6qdo5oVKB) on jqplay

One can also use `reduce`.

```sh
jq -nR 'reduce ( inputs | split(":\t") ) as [ $k, $v ] ( {}; . + { ($k): $v } )'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qNqEFl5ndg) on jqplay

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: exactly, actually it is far better to have a JSON object instead of an array :) thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Filter

```
reduce (inputs / ":\t") as [$key, $value] ({}; .+{($key): $value})
```

Input

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Output

```
{
  "Distributor ID": "Ubuntu",
  "Description": "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS",
  "Release": "20.04",
  "Codename": "focal"
}
```

Note that *each line* of `$key` and `$value` from `inputs` is processed and *combined* by `reduce`.

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/ZBvKf6vQ0F

Comment: That's identical to the solution posted 3 months earlier. You simply changed `| split(":\t")` to `/ ":\t"`. You didn't even explain why you provided different output than the OP requested.